# Python 3.4 how to create a line of text that always stays at the top of the screen while the script runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-curses

I'm trying to find a way to keep a fixed line of text displaying at the top of the screen the entire time a Python script runs.  Functionally, it would behave like the top line in nano editor; the program title remains at the top of the screen, even when scrolling through text in the editor area.  The idea is that the line would contain the name of the script that's running, and perhaps some dynamic information (progress indicators), and remain visible even when text output beneath that line scrolls.

From what I've researched so far, the curses module could possibly provide the foundation for reaching that goal.  I have yet to find a curses example that specifically demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish, and the learning curve is a bit steep for me at the moment.

The scripts would run on a Linux box without a GUI.

Thanks!

Comment: @plfabri Thank you for the suggestion, I will check out npyscreen.

Comment: You're welcome. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something simpler than *curses*, then look into using [**npyscreen**](https://npyscreen.readthedocs.io/introduction.html).

> This framework should be powerful enough to create everything from quick, simple programs to complex, multi-screen applications. It is designed to make doing the simple tasks very quick and to take much of the pain out of writing larger applications.

And it's built on `curses`.